# Carnival Ball toss game, how often will the same spot be hit

Tags: probability, games

I, unfortunately, am ignorant when it comes to statistical analysis. I do enjoy exercising my math brain with interesting questions. Here is the question that popped into my head and I don't know how to solve it.

A ball toss game has 36 divets for the ball to come to rest in. One green grand prize divet and 35 no winner divets. If allowed a large number of tosses, what percentage of the time will the ball land in the same green divet consecutively, after two tosses, after three tosses, etc. In other words, how does one calculate the percentage of not coming to rest in the winner divet after a certain amount of tosses for example 250 tosses?

I thought it would be an easy solution as 36 divets result in a chance of around 3%, but I have realized this is more complicated than it first appeared to be.

I am assuming there is a formula for this. Anyone interested in taking a shot at this?

I thank you in advance.

Comment: If $P(G) = 1/36$ and $X$ is number of G's in 250 independent tosses, then $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(250, 1/36)$ and $P(X=0) = (35/36)^{250} = 0.0008737474.$ Less than one chance in 1000. [Technical info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) about binomial distributions.

Comment: @Walter There's no clear reason why every divot would be equally probable, since different positions will not be exchangeable - e.g. an edge divot and a central divot aren't equivalent.  [Indeed with carnival games it's not unusual that by various means the winning outcome is also deliberately made harder (e.g. by a slight ridge at its edge or a slightly smaller indentation for the divot)] -- if you nonetheless wish to assume all divots are equiprobable you should state so explicitly in your question. In that case this is a standard sort of problem in beginner textbooks on probability... ctd

Comment: ctd... and is solved by computing the complementary event and making use of an independence assumption across tosses.